# Kivy BoundedNumericProperty errorhandler misbehaving

Tags: kivy

Edit: the odd behaviour in question is this - when using Kivy's BoundedNumericProperty() to prevent a numeric variable from straying outside set bounds, the code either works or it doesn't, depending on what lower bound is chosen.

Example code below to demonstrate the odd behaviour. If valueMin is set to 0, or 0.5, 1 etc the code behaves as expected. If it is set to 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 then we have  ValueError: ... is below the minimum bound ... Oddly also, normal service is restored if valueMin is set to 0.45, 0.35, 0.25 (but not 0.15). Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import BoundedNumericProperty

valueMin = 0.1
valueMax = 2

Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.9.2
<MainWidget>:
    Button:
        text: '+'
        on_press:
            root.number += root.step
    Button:
        text: '-'
        on_press:
            root.number -= root.step
    Label:
        text: str(root.number)
''')

class MainWidget(BoxLayout):
    global valueMin, valueMax
    step = 0.1
    number = BoundedNumericProperty(1, min=valueMin, max=valueMax, errorhandler=lambda x: valueMax if x > valueMax else valueMin)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        mw=MainWidget()
        return mw

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Seems to be a bug. You can report it here: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues

Comment: OK I reported it on github now: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5055